# Spelling of one syllable changes pronunciation of another

Tags: pronunciation, syllables, example

I've been fascinated by word pronunciations where changing the spelling of one syllable doesn't change *its* pronunciation, but rather changes *another* syllable in the word. The only two examples I can think of have very similar structures... the same vowels in both sets, where the changing of the second syllable vowel to either "a" or "e" changes how the "o" is pronounced in the first syllable.

The examples are:

Woman and Women

Modal and Model

Are there other examples of this? What are some possible reasons why the spelling is different for the unchanged syllable?

Thanks

Comment: English spelling doesn't represent its pronunciation, so if you're fascinated by inconsistency, you're in the right place. However, you really should stop thinking that there is any connection between the spelling of an English word or phrase (English spelling is a recent technological accident, frequently varied in practice) and its pronunciation (generated over centuries by what Sapir called the "mountainous and anonymous work of unconscious generations")

Comment: Do proper nouns count? How about Venice and Venus?

Comment: @JohnLawler - I have been looking for that quote since Witer Bash started, but I couldn't remember who said it. Thanks!

Comment: To piggyback on @John Lawler's point, there are other examples that don't fit the exact pattern you describe here, but still might be considered spelling oddities if you assumed that spelling reliably dictated pronunciation. Examples include: _oven/open, even/seven, haven/having, modem/modern, seven/even, money/movie, pint/pinto, miser/misery_ and _colony/colonel_.

Comment: There are also examples where the pronunciation changes without _any_ change in spelling, as with _produce_ (v) and _produce_ (n), or _progress_ (v) and _progress_ (n).

Comment: @medica Sapir, _Language_, 1921: "Everything that we have so far seen to be true of language points to the fact that it is the most significant and colossal work that the human spirit has evolved -- nothing short of a finished form of expression for all communicable experience. This form may be endlessly varied by the individual without thereby losing its distinctive contours; and it is constantly reshaping itself as is all art. Language is the most massive and inclusive art we know, a mountainous and anonymous work of unconscious generations."  [source](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/210.html)

Comment: @JohnLawler - beautiful and profound.